# Vielbein formalism

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, tensor-calculus

Maybe this a simple problem, But I couldn't solve it:
From Pierre Ramond's book (Field Theory: A Modern Primer, page 213):

$$[D_{m},D_{n}]=S_{mn}^{p}D_{p}+\frac{i}{2}R_{mn}^{pq}X_{pq}$$

So in order to get the expressions for S and R, he manifests in the book certain steps to reach to the answer.

$$[D_{m},D_{n}]=e^{\mu}_{m}(D_{\mu}e^{\rho}_{n})D_{\rho}+e^{\mu}_{m}e^{\rho}_{n}D_{\mu}D_{\rho}-(m\Leftrightarrow n)$$

This equation seems to show a kind of Leibnitz rule for $D_{\mu}$, but here is my problem I cannot get it.

$$[D_{m},D_{n}]=[e^{\mu}_{m}D_{\mu},e^{\nu}_{n}D_{\nu}]=e^{\mu}_{m}D_{\mu}e^{\nu}_{n}D_{\nu}-(m\Leftrightarrow n)\\
e^{\mu}_{m}D_{\mu}e^{\nu}_{n}D_{\nu}=e^{\mu}_{m}(\partial_{\mu}+i\omega_{\mu})e^{\nu}_{n}D_{\nu}=e^{\mu}_{m}(D_{\mu}e^{\nu}_{n})D_{\nu}+e^{\mu}_{m}e^{\nu}_{n}\partial_{\mu}D_{\nu}\\  
=e^{\mu}_{m}(D_{\mu}e^{\nu}_{n})D_{\nu}+e^{\mu}_{m}e^{\nu}_{n}D_{\mu}D_{\nu}-ie^{\mu}_{m}e^{\nu}_{n}\omega_{\mu}D_{\nu}$$

This last term spoil the equality (something wrong I did, but I cannot find it).

On the other hand, I would like to show this equality, too:

$$X_{pq}e^{\rho}_{n}=i\eta_{qn}e^{\rho}_{p}-i\eta_{pn}e^{\rho}_{q}$$

I've tried this:

$$X_{pq}\delta^{m}_{n}=i\eta_{qn}\delta^{m}_{p}-i\eta_{pn}\delta^{m}_{q}\\
X_{pq}=i\eta_{qm}\delta^{m}_{p}-i\eta_{pm}\delta^{m}_{q}$$

Is this last equality right?

Here $X_{pq}$ are the Lorentz generators for spinor representation, $D_{m}=e^{\mu}_{m}D_{\mu}$ and $D_{\mu}=\partial_{\mu}+\frac{i}{2}\omega_{\mu}^{mn}X_{mn}$.

Comment: Doesn't your extra term cancel out with the similar one from the expansion of the commutator?

Comment: $[-ie^{\mu}_{m}e^{\nu}_{n}+ie^{\mu}_{n}e^{\nu}_{m}]\omega_{\mu}D_{\nu}$

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: It is not a homework question, I want to get that result of the book. I think the problem is not right. It's for that reason I'm asking, to know if the equation is wrong or I made something bad.